# How to save int in SharedPreferences c# when app is going to be closed?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I want to save number of clicks in SharedPreferences in moment when app going closed. Now I have function for that connected with one button

```
   private void SaveClicks (){
    var prefs = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("Name",FileCreationMode.Private);
                 var prefEditor = prefs.Edit();
                 prefEditor.PutInt("Key", nametest);
                 prefEditor.Apply();

    }
```

"clicks" is name of int where I storage numbers of clicks in one of buttons

In what way I can do it automatically when app is going closed? Using onDestroy will be good solution?

//update
So I wrote that code:

```
protected override void OnDestroy()
        {
            var prefs = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("Name", FileCreationMode.Private); // 1
            var prefEditor = prefs.Edit(); // 2
            prefEditor.PutInt("Key", nametest); // 3
            prefEditor.Apply(); // 4


        }
```

And for counting clicks I have something like that

```
var prefs = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("Name", FileCreationMode.Private); // 1
            var value1 = prefs.GetInt("key", 0);
            if (clicks + value1 <= 499)
            {
                clicks++;
                textViewBattlepackCount.Text = (clicks + value1).ToString() + " clicks!";
                progressBarName1.Progress = progressBarName1.Progress + 1;
                nametest= clicks + value1;


                if (clicks + value1 == 500)
                {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    alertDialog.SetTitle("You won!");
                    alertDialog.SetMessage("message");
                    alertDialog.SetNeutralButton("Ok", delegate
                    {

                        alertDialog.Dispose();

                    });
                    alertDialog.Show();

                    clicks = 0;
                    nametest= 0;

                    textViewTXTCount.Text = "0";
                    progressBarName1.Progress = progressBarName1.Progress = 0;

                }
```

But the clicks in onDestroy() are storage only sometimes, one time there is correct number but another time after kill activity and restart app there is old number of clicks. I dont know why. 
Sorry for chaotic description

Comment: Depends on what you mean with "closed". Is it when it is not visible on the screen anymore or when the app is killed by Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your next question.

The SharedPreferences "key" should be covered when you call onDestory(), If not, please track the value of your "nametest" using debug

BTW

```
  prefEditor.PutInt("Key", nametest);
  var value1 = prefs.GetInt("key", 0);
```

Please using the same "Key"  - -!!

Comment: Ohh ofc :D Thanks again mate.

Answer (score 1):

It depends your requirement:

1. If u just want to store the numbers of click when the activity be killed. Using OnDestory()
2. If u want to store the numbers of click when the activity is in the background(e.g. you press the home button or another activity started), please using onPause();
3. onSaveInstanceState() can also be invoked before the activity destroyed, it can restore some temporary data (e.g. the text in EditText).

Comment: Great! Thanks for help. :)

Comment: Can I ask you for help one more time? I just edited my question.